# Destructors of block-scope statics can be called several times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I just read [this](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/articles/implementing_mutexes.html) article about the actual reasons behind the current `boost::mutex` implementation and noticed the following phrase:

> Block-scope statics have the additional problem of a potential race
>   condition on "the first time through", which can lead to the
>   destructor being run multiple times on popular compilers, which is
>   undefined behaviour — compilers often use the equivalent of a call to
>   atexit in order to ensure that destruction is done in the reverse
>   order of construction, and the initialization race that may cause the
>   constructor to be run twice may also cause the destructor to be
>   registered twice

Is it true? Should I really check whether another thread already inside this object's destructor via atomic operations or something like this? Should I do it even in C++11 - C++14? Because as far as I know there's no more "constructor for the same local object with static storage duration can be called simultaneously from several threads" problem since C++11 -- it requires that another threads should wait for the constructor's completion. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this article was written pre C++11, it says amongst other things:

> [...] next version of the C++ Standard, scheduled to be released in 2009.[...]

and this was the case pre C++11, it was unspecified what happened in this case since threading was not part of memory model pre C++11.

This changed in C++11 and the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `6.7` *Declaration statement* says (*emphasis mine*):

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of **all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration** (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place. [...] Otherwise
>   such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through
>   its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the
>   completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by
>   throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will
>   be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. **If
>   control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is
>   being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion
>   of the initialization.** [...]

Pre C++11 we have to treat the static local variable just like we treat any other critical section. We can find a excellent description of the situation pre C++11 in the post [C++ scoped static initialization is not thread-safe, on purpose!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx).

Comment: How does to race condition affect the destruction of static variables pre-c++11? Isn't the compiler in charge of any threads that clean up static objects?

Comment: @user2079303 if multiple instantiations are done then you could get multiple destructor calls. Since the standard did not specify a multi-threaded memory model the implementation was free to deal with this situation in any possible way.

Comment: And how should we deal with it in case of pre-C++11?

Comment: @FrozenHeart you have to treat it just like any other critical section in a multi-threaded situation.