# Possible bug with simultaneous write to the same memory region in boost::mutex constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

As was previously discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689895/destructors-of-block-scope-statics-can-be-called-several-times) question, a pre-C++11 implementation can execute code in the way when several threads simultaneously call constructor for the same object with static storage duration.

In `boost::mutex` implementation there's `initialize` function that is called from its constructor and contains the following code:

```
        void initialize()
        {
            active_count=0;
            event=0;
        }
```

Well, it seems for me that it's UB since we can have situation when several threads simultaneously write `0` to the same memory region, isn't it?

Comment: Care to share a reasonable example of when this comes up? That makes It easier to show what's wrong with the example/how to fix that

Comment: Ok, it has become apparent that the question is about initialization of function-local statics pre c++11. I'll note this has **zero** to do with `boost::mutex`. But, yes, `boost::mutex` is _also_ unsafe for cases like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you simultaneously construct a mutex in the same memory location from different threads then you're invoking UB.

Of course, that scenario is really really hard to achieve.

**Update**

Ok, it has become apparent that the question is about initialization of function-local statics pre c++11. Although this has nothing to do with boost::mutex, per se, I can confirm that, indeed, `boost::mutex` construction is also unsafe for cases like that.

---

(Mutexes that coordinate access to a shared resource typically need to precede access to the resource. When the mutex itself is a shared resource before it is created, you're doing it wrong.

You need existing synchronization to coordinate access to the are in which you construct new mutexes if you even need to do something like this.)

Comment: I'm just reading this (https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/articles/implementing_mutexes.html) article where author tries to go through the current `boost::mutex` implementation and tries to achieve the pre-C++11 compatibility even in case of simultaneous constructor calls. Well, then there's no general solution to this and the current `boost::mutex` implementation with all its suggestions and checks is broken anyway?

Comment: Oh like that.  They can achieve that with some kind of barrier, I guess. But yeah, boost's constructor is not meant to be thread safe. That's not broken. It's perfectly fine. It's the memory model and initialization guarantees pre-c++ that are "broken" (C++ didn't have a memory model and as such was not thread aware. Full stop.)

Comment: It seems a bit strange for me because there's a lot of code in `boost::mutex` implementation which relies on the idea that constructors and destructors can be called simultaneously from several threads, but **not** in this particular case with default initialization

Comment: Can you link me to any piece of documentation that states that? I think it's plain wrong. The same goes for many operations (like construction, resize etc.) on all of the lock free containers in boost.

Comment: I think that this information doesn't represent in any official docs, but I saw a lof of code with Interlocked* functions calls to ensure that object's constructing and destructing won't mess up everything in case of multithreading

Comment: @FrozenHeart Not with boost mutex. You could, of course simply add an _`atomic_flag`_ to guard your construction (that wasn't in the question, so I didn't mention it)